# Fusing convolutions

Tags: convolution

I am attempting to combine two consecutive 2D convolutions into a single 2D convolution. Ideally, a convolution operation is a linear transformation, so it should be possible to merge two linear transformations into one.

In practice, I have performed all the necessary calculations to derive the fused kernel. I began with two 3x3 2D convolutions, each with a stride of 1 and padding of 1, and attempted to merge them into a single 5x5 convolution with a stride of 1 and padding of 2.

The results indicated that these operations are equivalent for most of the image except for the borders. The pixels processed at the border of the input are different, and it's impossible to set the padding differently to achieve equivalence. So, what is happening? I also attempted to train a 5x5 Conv2D model to mimic the operations and obtained results similar to my algebraic derivation of the kernel, but they still aren't equivalent.

What could be the explanation for this?

2 linear layer con be fused to 1 linear layer, but 2 conv cannot always be fused to 1 conv.
how is it possible, and what the name of this thing?

Comment: Hi! I think you should simply write down your two 3x3 kernels, and the resultant 5x5 kernel too...

Comment: Share the kernel and we'll derive through the process.